# Is is allowed to read fields or properties within a Backgroundtask?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Background**
I have two programs and both shall communicate trough namedpipe, based on the current state of the external application my Mainapplication shall wait, but without blocking my UI.

In this Tutorial (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-async-await-and-dispatcher-in-C-Sharp/) is shown, that I have to use a dispatcher to access the UI Elements, but I'm using MVVM Pattern to bind my Properties to the UI.

Question:

1. Do I have to use a dispatcher in my Example too? I do not get any exception until now.
2. Can I access (read) fields or properties within my Backgroundtask or is forbidden?

   ```
   public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
   {
       // PropertyChanged is done trough Fody.PropertyChanged


       public int CurrentIndex { get; set; }
       public DelegateCommand StartCommand { get; set; }
       private Process _clientprocess;
       private NamedPipeServer<string> _server;
       private List<string> mylist;
       enum State { WaitForConnection = 0, Connected = 1, WaitForProcessExit = 2, Exited = 4 }

       private State _statemaschine;


       public MainWindowViewModel()
       {
           StartCommand = new DelegateCommand(StartCommandMethod);
           mylist = new List<string>();
       }

       private void StartCommandMethod()
       {
           mylist.Add("One");
           mylist.Add("Two");
           var currentindex = 0;
           _statemaschine = State.Exited;
           _server = new NamedPipeServer<string>("MyPipe");
           _server.ClientConnected += ServerOnClientConnected;
           _server.ClientDisconnected += ServerOnClientDisconnected;
           _server.Start();
            var info = new ProcessStartInfo
           {
               CreateNoWindow = false,
               UseShellExecute = true,

               FileName = @".\ClientTest.exe"
           };
           _clientprocess = new Process { StartInfo = info };

           _clientprocess.Exited += Clientprocess_Exited;
           _clientprocess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
           Task.Run((() =>
           {
               while (currentindex < mylist.Count)
               {
                   switch (_statemaschine)
                   {
                       case State.Exited:
                           _clientprocess.Start();
                           _statemaschine++;
                           while (_statemaschine == State.WaitForConnection)
                           {
                           }
                           break;

                       case State.Connected:
                           _server.PushMessage(mylist[currentindex]);
                           while (_statemaschine == State.Connected)
                           {
                           }
                           _statemaschine = State.WaitForProcessExit;
                           break;
                       case State.WaitForProcessExit:
                           while (_statemaschine == State.Exited)
                           {

                           }
                           _statemaschine = State.Exited;
                           currentindex++;
                           break;

                       case State.WaitForConnection:
                           break;

                   }
               }
           }));

       }

       private void ServerOnClientDisconnected(NamedPipeConnection<string, string> connection)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("Disconnected");
       }

       private void ServerOnClientConnected(NamedPipeConnection<string, string> connection)
       {
           _statemaschine = State.Connected;
           Debug.WriteLine("Client connected");

       }

       private void Clientprocess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
       {
           _statemaschine = State.Exited;
           Debug.WriteLine("Exited");
       }
   ```

Comment: It is "allowed", you just need to be cautious of how you do it and mark appropriate fields as `volatile` or use locking if you are modifying fields. Usually reading fields is not a problem, the issue comes when you are modifying them on multiple threads.

Comment: I'm accessing in the Task and UI the _statemschine state, means I shall lock this?

Comment: Yes, there is a contention there and possible issue if both the task and the UI change `statemaschine` at the same time, it is possible that one of those will be lost. You should synchronize access, but you can't lock an enum you'll need to create a synchronization object to lock.

Comment: But it seems you do not  access any UI elements in that task, so where exactly are you going to use Dispatcher?

Comment: The public property CurrentIndex is binded to my UI. I shall re-think my code to avoid multithreading issues.